# libvirt API - overlays, backing image

Tags: overlay, virtualization, qemu, libvirt, backing

Is there a possibility to create 2(or more) different overlays from one base image using libvirt API ?

```
FedoraBase.img <-- FedoraGuest1.qcow2
                \
                  <-- FedoraGuest2.qcow2
```

So FedoraBase is backing image for Guest1 and Guest2 overlays...

Using qemu-img tool you can create it like this:

```
qemu-img create -b /export/vmimages/FedoraBase.img -f qcow2 \ 
       /export/vmimages/FedoraGuest1.qcow2

qemu-img create -b /export/vmimages/FedoraBase.img -f qcow2 \ 
       /export/vmimages/FedoraGuest2.qcow2
```

But I can not find any libvirt API doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

This task requires you to use the libvirt storage pool APIs - in particular qcow2 images can be created using the virStorageVolCreateXML() API. This API accepts an [XML document](http://libvirt.org/formatstorage.html#StorageVol) that describes the desired configuration and gives you the ability to specify the backing file. This should let achieve the layering you describe.

Comment: could you provide a more detailed example? it's kind of hard to parse the libvirt documentation...